# Shadow kill, does it remove loot from bodies?

Tags: dishonored

I was thinking about using shadow kill (level 2) but will it remove the loot from the dead persons body? (i.e them carrying 50 coins, if I shadow kill them will I not be able to loot it?)

Answer (score 10):

No, it doesn't. You can still loot and it's even easier because the body doesn't hide the loot.